# Show that $-2abX \le a^2Y +b^2Z\implies 4X^2 \le 4 Y Z $, $a,b \in \mathbb R $, $X;Y;Z \ge 0 $

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Show that $-2abX \le a^2Y +b^2Z\implies 4X^2 \le 4YZ $

where $X,Y,Z $ are nonnegative and $a,b \in \mathbb R $.

---

This looks almost as I could use Young's inequality, but not quiet.

---

The above comes from a proof that claims that for $X,Y \in L ^2(P) $ ,

$(2E[|XY |])^2\le 4 E [X ^2]E [Y^2 ]  $

assuming $X,Y $ to be nonnegative and bounded. Then I can prove Schwartz inequality using monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Put $b=\pm 1$ and consider it a quadratic in $a$. Now the discriminant needs to be negative.

Comment: And what does this say?

Comment: Why don't you work it out? The discriminant is $4X^2-4YZ$. If it's negative, what do you get?

Comment: But why need the discriminant be negative, or why can't we have any root?

Comment: real root that is

Comment: If we have two real roots, the quadratic will change signs. Which means the original inequality will be violated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that the discriminant need to be nonpositive, since the original equation can be zero ( ie have one root)?

Comment: Glad you worked that out. The inequalities in the problem are not strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to clarify the question. I suppose you are intend to ask:

If for all $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $-2ab X\le a^2Y+b^2 Z$, then $X^2\le YZ$.

In this case, 
$$
2YZ=\min_{a,b} \{\frac{a^2Y+b^2 Z}{|ab|} \} \ge  2|X|,
$$
proving the claim.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: How is min $(a^2Y+b^2 Z)=2 |xb |YZ $?